# set delimiter when using sp_send_dbmail (csv file)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query that brings me back a result set but when I use `sp_send_dbmail`to send an email to someone containing this result set as a **CSV file** it opens in excel in the incorrect format! I know that I can correct this format through excel but I don't want the user to do that! I want them to just be able to open the file and everything be visible in the correct format. Below shows how I am creating the **CSV file** and emailing it out the someone (I am also specifying the seperator but it doesn't work and I can't figure out why):

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name='TestProfile',
@recipients='Test@gmail.com',
@subject='Test message',
@body='This is a test.',

@query = 'Select firstName, LastName, Address, Score from TestData.dbo.Student',
@query_result_header = 0,
@exclude_query_output = 1,
@append_query_error = 1,
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_result_separator = ',',
@query_result_width = 25,
@query_attachment_filename = 'Test.csv',
@query_result_no_padding = 1
```

Once the **CSV File** is received and opened all the data is represented in the first column, which isn't the desired results!

[image]

Screenshot of my list seperator settings

[image]

Comment: @DrCopyPaste is absolutely right about the `List Separator` but from my experience `.csv` file will be always opened correctly if you will use `tab` symbol as list separator.

Comment: This probably involves the [windows global list separator](http://www.solveyourtech.com/change-the-windows-7-list-separator/) which excel uses to find column limits, unfortunately you will have to ensure this, since this setting can vary on different machines. I am not sure, but I found `;` to be the default setting for most machines I looked at this setting, you should check what your clients machines use and what your local setting is.

Comment: my local setting is `,` and it still doesn't work! I also noticed that the column names aren't included in the CSV file for come reason

Comment: @user3538102 ok, now that sounds strange, do you maybe have a `sample csv, without sensitive data`, for us to play with? (A few lines should suffice)

Comment: I can give you a basic CSV which only has two pieces of data on it but how can I send you the file?

Comment: hm since you use `,` as delimiter it should be absolutely okay to include a few lines of your csv into your question as code.

Comment: I have added an image to display what I am getting for 2 students! As you can see the column names are not visible but I suspect that the issue with the columns is down to the names of the columns not being included!

Answer (score 7):

I struggled with this issue for a couple of days , but finally got it to work

**@query_result_separator ='     '**, did the trick, it's TAB as the result separator.

Full code
            EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

```
              @profile_name ='MailProfile',
              @from_address = 'def@abc.com',
              @recipients = 'Abc@abc.com',
              @body = @varBody,
              @body_format = 'HTML',
              @execute_query_database ='MyDB',
              @query = @VarSQL,
              @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
              @query_result_separator ='    ',
              @exclude_query_output =1,
              @query_result_no_padding=1,
              @query_result_header =1,
              @query_attachment_filename ='MyDB.csv'
```

Comment: I also got it to work with TAB but I thought I posted my answer on the forum but I mustn't have! Thanks

Comment: How do you embed the tab character?

Comment: @RonJohn in the stored procedure, just hit tab on the keyboard within the string. It will save that formatting and show up correctly in excel

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Excel anyway, you can override Excel list separator and remove the problem all together, across every single regional setting out there.

Add the following line in the beginning of the CSV file: **sep=;**

In your example you would have this inside your @query.

```
..
@query_result_separator = ';',
@query = '
print ''sep=;''
SELECT 1,2'
..
```

Content of csv:

```
sep=;
1;2
```

Result; correct separation. Always!

[image: Column Separation in Excel, using forced separator]

Comment: great idea the print ''sep=;'' much bettere than many other solutions that append to first column name

Answer (score 0):

*I think I could reproduce your issue with the data you provided. I found the answer in this [superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/408191/excel-ignores-system-list-separator).*

It seems, **Excel ignores your list separator if it is the same character as another already used character** (for example decimal separator), it will work when you switch decimal separator to something else. But since you need this working on other client machines, too, you should consider switching to another csv-separator altogether (`;`?)

Comment: so what your saying is my SQL query should look like this, `Select firstName; LastName; Address; Score from TestData.dbo.Student` and then have the seperator as `;`

Comment: No, in SQL you will still use `,` to separate columns in a SELECT-statement, it is probably only this `@query_result_separator = ','` setting you will have to change to `;`

Comment: I changed the `@query_result_separator = ','` but it still isn't separating the data but the column headers aren't included in the CSV file which I believe is the problem! Do you know of any reason why my code in the original question wouldn't return the column names!

Comment: @user3538102 You have to change the `@query_result_separator = ','` setting **AND** [change the windows list separator setting](http://www.solveyourtech.com/change-the-windows-7-list-separator/) to make it work.

Comment: I changed the windows list separator and nothing has changed! The column names is the issue that will solve the problem I think but just don't understand why the column names aren't being returned!

Comment: @user3538102 the column headers are not included, because you did not want them - `@query_result_header = 0`, should set this to 1 to include them, if you changed your `list separator setting` and  `query_result_separator` and it still is not working you should also include a screenshot of the dialog configuring the separator, maybe there are still some inconsistencies.

Comment: ok I have set the column headers to visible now but the issue is still not resolved! I have added the screenshot to the original question!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68651/discussion-between-user3538102-and-drcopypaste).

Comment: I couldn't sort the issue of why I couldn't split the data on the delimiter `;` or  `,` but when I looked at excel it automatically tried to separate on `tab` so I just used the same in my SQL and that sorted the issue but this has lead onto another issue now which can be seen in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906594/csv-file-splitting-my-row-data-into-separate-rows

Answer (score 0):

You can't count on user regional settings or the application used to open the file.

Besides, any Excel user should know about **Data->Text To Columns** function.

The only thing you should take care of are fields that might contain the field separator (`,`) like addresses which should be wrapped with **text qualifiers** (e.g. `"`).