# CSV file splitting my row data into separate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a a query that creates a CSV file and then emails it out to a user but the CSV file is not in the correct format. For some reason when the CSV file is opened it is separating some of my rows into 2 separate rows for some unknown reason! The spliting of the rows seems to be getting done at random because some rows are split while other rows remain intact. This is a difficult scenario to explain so below shows the query I have wrote for creating the CSV file and emailing it out to the user and then the results of the CSV file!

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name='TestProfile',
@recipients='Test@gmail.com',
@subject='Test message',
@body='This is a test.',
@query = 'Select *
FROM (
SELECT 
    replace(LEFT(convert(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 106),6) + ''-'' + RIGHT(year(convert(NVARCHAR, getdate(), 106)),2), '' '', ''-'') as [Date],
    FirstName, Surname,TestTime as TestTime ,  Percentage as Percentage, Score as Score       
FROM TestDatabase.dbo.TestingTable
) as s
PIVOT
(
SUM(Score)
FOR [TestTime] IN ([00:00],[00:30],[01:00],[01:30],[02:00],[02:30],[03:00],[03:30],[04:00],[04:30],[05:00],[05:30],[06:00],[06:30],[07:00],[07:30],[08:00],[08:30],[09:00],[09:30],[10:00],[10:30],[11:00],[11:30],[12:00],[12:30],[13:00],[13:30],[14:00],[14:30],[15:00],[15:30],[16:00],[16:30],[17:00],[17:30],[18:00],[18:30],[19:00],[19:30],[20:00],[20:30],[21:00],[21:30],[22:00],[22:30],[23:00],[23:30])
) Results
',
@query_result_separator = ' ',
@query_result_header = 1,
@exclude_query_output = 1,
@append_query_error = 1,
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1, 
@query_attachment_filename = 'test.csv',
@query_result_no_padding = 1
```

**Output**

[image]

When in fact it should look like this:

[image]

Bottom image is the correct format and the top row goes from `00.00` to `23.30` as intended!

Comment: Emailing the file as an attachment, or are you putting the content in the email body?

Comment: It is being emailed as an attachment!

Comment: Good! Or bad seeing as that's the easy potential source of such an error. Thing you have to find out now is where is it going wrong. e.g. if you just create the file are there any extra end of line delimiters appearing in there. If not, if you import the file as the recipient is doing do you get the issue, etc. Could be any number of problems this.

Comment: the user won't be importing the file! they just want to open it in excel and see the data! If I run the query in SQL Management Studio and then right click to export the data to CSV then the data is correct!

Comment: for excel to interpert a new line, a new line feed and new line must have been used.  Open the CSV in a notepad.  Do you see multiple lines for the same record?  if so then the utility generating the CSV is somehow adding vbcrlf or line feed and return to the record.

Comment: Opening it in excel is an import. Come on guy. You have a query, a write to a file, an email and an import. Check through each stage see where the problem is introduced. Debugging 101.

Comment: I thought you meant exporting it back into SQL management studio! A simple mis-understanding! No need to make me look stupid `come on guy`!

Answer (score 3):

By default, [`sp_send_dbmail`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307(v=sql.100).aspx) inserts a line break after 256 characters on any given line.  You can modify this by specifying the `@query_result_width` parameter when calling the stored procedure.  Maximum value is 32767.

Aside: If this is supposed to be a CSV file, why is `@query_result_separator = ' '` and not `@query_result_separator = ','`?